# How can I connect to an InterBase database using Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, sql

There is an InterBase database that I'd like to connect to using Excel. I have the database name, address, and login info. IB, as I understand it, is a form of SQL.

Using the SQL connect mode under "Data" in Excel does not work, however. I would guess that I need some kind of driver to go between the two as InterBase is proprietary.

I can successfully ping the server, so I know it's there. I have verified that the login info is correct.

What steps do I need to take to get Excel to work?

Comment: This may help http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010167227.aspx I assume you have the drivers installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Interbase ODBC drivers to be installed on the PC where Excel lives.
You then define the connection with the ODBC admin tool (odbcad32.exe).
From Excel you then select this ODBC connection.

Please note: If you run a 64-bit Windows version you will have to pay attention.
It can be quite confusing.
If you run the normal 32-bit Office, you will have to install the 32-bit version of the ODBC drivers. (These needs to be the same bit-size as the application.)
The default ODBC admin tool (odbcad32.exe) though will be the 64-bit one (from c:\Windows\System32) with which you can't configure the 32-bit driver.
To configure the 32-bit driver on a 64-bit OS you will have to explicitly start the 32-bit version of odbcadm32.exe which lives in c:\Windows\SysWOW64.

(If you are one of the few people in the world running the 64-bit Office version you will need the 64-bit ODBC drivers and the default odbc admin tool is the right one to use.)